# Too many items to be highlighted on a mobile app list view

Tags: usability, mobile, longlist

I have a screen that the user can observe past transactions of the credit card. There can be 40-50 rows (on average) on the screen, scrollable downwards. I would like to offer one feature for some of the items on the list, and another feature for the remaining items. How should I highlight those items and do not over-stuff the screen. Coloring? Assigned tooltip sized icons on each row? Other suggestions are also more than welcome.

Comment: Does the user visit this screen primarily to view past transactions or to use these features you want to introduce?

Comment: Thanks for the Q. The user visits the screen to view past transactions. This is like, i will offer some payment relief options. Yet, not sure if to use a cosmetic flags-notifiers next to relevant transactions thru the page (which seems to be a shorter cut or insert these options as a general offer between or below the lines.)

Comment: What data do you currently have in each list item? Do you have a mockup available?

Comment: Without a look at the cells in their rows, and their contents, it's impossible to make a generalisation about this with any kind of accuracy.

Comment: I will try to add a mockup for mobile shortly. andre, confused, thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1):

With the little information given, I would recommend putting a simple button into the cells with the function that's applicable to this cell.

Assumptions I made:

- Functions are exclusive (on any tx, at most one function applicable)
- Items not already overcrowded
- There's a simple, short term recognizable for the user to identify the function
- You're on a mobile device (where a toolbar is not the standard solution to this)